# getting ERROR 1452 (23000) if inserting csv file from shell script code

Tags: mysql, shell, csv

This is my shell script to insert  csv data into my mysql table but we are getting the below error.

> "ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 1: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`inv_impact`.`asset_ext_warranty`,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_asset_ext_warranty` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`)
>   REFERENCES `vendor` (`vendor_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION)"

Shell script is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=,
while read offering auth_no DOP price extend_from extend_to status vendor_id
do echo "INSERT INTO asset_ext_warranty(offering, auth_no, DOP, price, extend_from, extend_upto, status, vendor_id) VALUES ('$offering','$auth_no','$DOP','$price','$extend_from','$extend_upto','$status','$vendor_id');"  done < warr-ext.csv | mysql -uroot -p'pass' dbname;
```

while the parents table has the vendor_id with the referencing values

```
vendor_id | vendor_name                | person_name        | phone_no      | mail_id                   | vendor_detail                                                                      |
+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         1 | nsiah              | Hshiwq      | 0981002364   | suajs@yahoo.co.in | NULL                                                                               |
|         2 | Dell International service | Dell               | 1800-425-4026 | NULL                      | NULL                                                                               |
|         3 | Integral system ltd        | Mamata             | NULL          | NULL                      | NULL
```

the child row(vendor_id) in *csv* file has the same value as parents row .

Comment: did you try to insert one row of the excel file? Seems stupid, but you never know if you have a small error in your query. And maybe you should remove the ' ' from the '$vendor_id', as it is a numeric value, not a text

Comment: Somewhere in the data you are using a vendor_id not present in the vendor table. You need to find out which one.